# jQuery functions not working properly on production (Heroku)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm doing some simple querying and assigning within Bootstrap modals using jQuery. Everything works fine locally but the handlers are not working in production on Heroku. An example issue:

In the view:

```
<p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" data-value-attr="<%= b.value %>" class="edit-link">
```

In the JS:

```
$('.edit-link').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).data('value-attr'));
        $('#editModalTitle').append($(this).data('value-attr'));
    });
```

That click handler is defined in the js file for that view, as part of `$(document).ready(function()...`

Both the console logging and the updating of the UI values work locally. Neither work in production.

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: @jvillian I am using the turbolinks gem, yes. v 5.0

Comment: You might want to read the [Turbolinks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#turbolinks) section of the [Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) guide. Specifically, look for the `$(document).on "turbolinks:load"` bit. That may or may not be your problem, but that `$(document).ready(function()...` bit looks suspicious.

Comment: @jvillian Thanks for your suggestion. I've updated my js to instead use `$(document).on("turbolinks:load", (function()...`. While the desired behavior does still persist locally, this does not fix the issue on the production environment. Any other ideas?

Comment: @jvillian I removed turbolinks from my app entirely (removed gem, removed attributes in link tags in application layout, removed include from application.js, restored scoped js file to original jQuery) but the JS is still not functioning on production. It does still work locally. Do you know what I might be missing?